# Copy variable content to clipboard in java-script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need help in this script. I have to get list items and need to copy to clipboard

```
var x = $('ul .pull-left').text(); 
x.execCommand("Copy");
alert(x);
```

this script workings data is getting and also alerting but x.execCommand is not working. 
I need to copy the variable value. Also the list getting is merge and i want to break items as they actually are. How can i do this.

Comment: Try https://clipboardjs.com/